# Electric Potential of a "body"

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, definition

We know that electrostatic potential is defined for a "point " in space but today when i was studying capacitance chapter i encountered phrases like "potential of earth" and "potenial of plate" and "plate is at a potential" . I wanna ask, is potential also defined for a body, and not only for a point in space? If yes, then how is it defined? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Potential of a body" is only defined for conductor bodies. Since they are conductors, the electric potential is the same everywhere inside them or on the surface. So it is equivalent to the potential of any point of it.

Comment: So do you mean that potential of a body is actually refers to the potential on its surface?

Comment: @AnkurYadav The surface and the inside are actually equi-potential. So, to refer to the potential of that body, you can refer to the potential of some point on the surface or inside the body.

Comment: I got it thankyou so much for gour courtesy really

Comment: @AnkurYadav If this answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as "accepted answer" by [clicking on the tickmark](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) below the vote count.